# How can I read and store specific part of a line from a file using c++?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am trying to make a Quiz game using c++, for that I want to store all my questions(MCQs) line by line along with their answer in a text file.

In the following format
"what is it? a)x b)y c)z d)p"  'a'

Now I want to read from the file and store it in my quiz game.That is question in a string variable and answer in char variable.

Then I wish to check if the user inputs the right answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

 using namespace std;


 int NoOfQuestions = 2;
int counter = 0;
 int main(){
  ifstream file("c++.txt");

  string question;
  char a;

  while(counter<NoOfQuestions){

      getline(file,question);
      cout<<question<<endl;
      counter++;
  }




}
```

Comment: [std::string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)? You can store the string in a [std::stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and use [std::geline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with a delimiter

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your file looks like this. You have two questions. The first one has 3 answers, the second one has two answers:

```
Is the Earth flat?
3
Yes
No
Maybe
Is the sky blue?
2
Yes
It's cloudy
```

We can create a struct to represent the question:

```
struct Question {
    std::string question;
    std::vector<std::string> answers; 
};
```

And then we can write a function to read it in using the `>>` operator:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Question& q) {
    // Get the question
    std::getline(stream, q.question);

    // Get the number of answers
    int num_answers;
    stream >> num_answers; 

    // Ignore the rest of the line containing the number of answers
    std::string _ignore; 
    std::getline(stream, _ignore); 

    // Read the answers
    q.answers.resize(num_answers); 
    for(auto& answer : q.answers) {
        std::getline(stream, answer); 
    }
    return stream; 
}
```

#### Example usage:

```
int main() {
    // First block: write the file and close it
    {
        std::ofstream file("test.txt");
        file << "Is the earth flat?\n";
        file << "3  \n"; 
        file << "Yes\n";
        file << "No\n"; 
        file << "Mabye\n"; 
    }

    // Second block: open the file, and read it
    {
        std::ifstream file("test.txt");
        Question q;
        file >> q;
        std::cout << "Question: " << q.question << '\n'; 
        std::cout << "Answers: \n"; 

        for(auto& answer : q.answers) {
            std::cout << answer << '\n'; 
        }

    }
}
```